# Change rectangle color

Tags: c#, wpf

Given this function:

```
private void Rectangle_Slut_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{

}
```

I want to do something like:

```
this.background = backgroundcolor.change
```

like you can do in a console application. I've seen similar questions but they do it in XAML.

Comment: `there's only one way to learn it.` That is so not true.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I've edited out the irrelevant comments, please read [ask] before you ask your next question so that's easier to get an answer

Comment: That looks suspiciously like an event handler. What type of object are you trying to change the background color of?

Comment: @Mike_G Your second link is about `Button`s which do have a `Background` property

Comment: But it isn't possible to use (sender as Rectangle).Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.F032838); 
a special color like F032838 though?

Comment: `((Rectangle)sender).Fill = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#FF032838");`

Answer (score 0):

As long as your `Rectangle` is calling the event handler, you can access it like so:

```
private void Rectangle_Slut_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{
    (sender as Rectangle).Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red); 
}
```

Comment: `sender as Rectangle` should be `(Rectangle)sender`. Thus you would correctly get an InvalidCastException in case sender is not a Rectangle, instead of an incorrect NullReferenceException. It's also redundant to create a SolidColorBrush, when you could simply use `Brushes.Red`.